# AngularJS-Datatable Issues with Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/dataReloadWithPromise

The issues is that I am having trouble implementing the reloading/loading of data. I am not getting any errors but it states that there is no data to show in the table.

**controller**

```
defaultApp.controller('WebIntegrationController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$rootScope', '$anchorScroll', '$timeout', 'WebIntegrationService', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope, $anchorScroll, $timeout, WebIntegrationService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

    this.pushList = [];
    this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
        return WebIntegrationService.getPushList();
    }).withBootstrap();
    this.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('ProductNumber').withTitle('Product Number').withClass('text-danger'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('UserRequested').withTitle('Created By'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('TimeStamp').withTitle('Entry Date')
    ];
    this.dtInstance = {};
}]);
```

**service**

```
defaultApp.factory('WebIntegrationService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getPushList: function () {
            return $http.get('/web/getpushlist');
        },
    }
}]);
```

**Frontend**

```
<div class="container-fluid gray-bg" ng-controller="WebIntegrationController as wiCtrl">
    <table datatable="" dt-options="wiCtrl.dtOptions" dt-columns="wiCtrl.dtColumns" dt-instance="wiCtrl.dtInstance" class="table table-striped table-bordered"></table>
</div>
```

**JSON at /web/getpushlist**

```
[{"ProductNumber":"AK-19B","UserRequested":"Ya Wang","TimeStamp":"06/01/2016 01:00 PM"},{"ProductNumber":"BTC-24","UserRequested":"Ya Wang","TimeStamp":"06/01/2016 01:00 PM"}]
```

**$http reference for returning a promise**

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing one little part

```
 this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function () {
    return WebIntegrationService.getPushList();
}).withBootstrap().withDataProp('data');
```

.withDataProp setting found in docs